# Does metasploit works on localhost?

Tags: mysql, localhost, metasploit

I installed Metasploit community edition on my local machine and tried to exploit my own localhost with `auxiliary/admin/mysql/mysql_sql` module.

I also provided my mysql credentials and when I `run` the auxiliary there is a timeout error.

```
msf5 auxiliary(admin/mysql/mysql_sql) > show options

Module options (auxiliary/admin/mysql/mysql_sql):

   Name      Current Setting   Required  Description
   ----      ---------------   --------  -----------
   PASSWORD  password          no        The password for the specified username
   RHOSTS    127.0.0.1         yes       The target address range or CIDR identifier
   RPORT     3306              yes       The target port (TCP)
   SQL       select version()  yes       The SQL to execute.
   USERNAME  developer         no        The username to authenticate as

msf5 auxiliary(admin/mysql/mysql_sql) > run
[*] Running module against 127.0.0.1

[-] 127.0.0.1:3306 - Connection timedout
[*] Auxiliary module execution completed
msf5 auxiliary(admin/mysql/mysql_sql) >
```

even if I turned off my firewall, the response is the same.

1. Does Metasploit allow to exploit its own host pc?
2. If so what could be the reason for `Connection timed out`?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your MySQL server accessible over the network? Out of the box, they aren't.

Comment: @Jos I believe so, How do I get confirmed that my MySQL server is accessible over the network?
There is a user who has privileges to access MySQL over network

Comment: In other words, does `ss -nl|grep 3306` turn up anything?

Comment: To make the server accessible over the network, edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and change the `bind-address` parameter to the proper IP address.

Comment: @Jos, instead of trying with localhost, I tried to exploit one of my own droplets which I have MySQL access over the network. but still getting `Connection timedout` error. I made sure that 3306 is opened on my droplet firewall. (I did nmap scan from my local machine to get confirmed)

Comment: That makes it a rather different question. You should turn on logging in MySQL to see if anything reaches the server.

Comment: Well, I accessed the Mysql server on droplet from my local pc. BTW I bound my local IP as you suggested. and **after that**, I could able to connect to my local MySQL server using `mysql -h 192.168.8.101 -p -u developer` and tried to exploit. 


when I use `127.0.0.1` as RHOSTS, it gives me `[-] 127.0.0.1:3306 - Auxiliary failed: Rex::ConnectionRefused The connection was refused by the remote host (127.0.0.1:3306).`
when I use `192.168.8.101` as RHOSTS, it shows `connection timedout`